# How to return notebook's own file name

Tags: notebooks, files-and-directories

What command within a notebook will return the file name of that notebook?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have to add a few extra commands to `NotebookFileName` to remove the directory.

```
Last@FileNameSplit@NotebookFileName[]
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: if you don't need the extension you can do it even shorter: `FileBaseName@NotebookFileName[]`. If you know the extension is `.nb` then `(FileBaseName@NotebookFileName[])<>".nb"`

Answer (score 11):

No need to go through all the machinations of trimming/applying a cascade of functions, simply:

```
CurrentValue["NotebookFileName"]
```